# Colourspace conversion using cuda in C++

Tags: c++, opencv, cuda

My aim is to load an image with opencv and apply a colourspace conversion using cuda. Initial colourspace I am trying to convert to is YUV422 from RGB. However the conversion is returning Height: 0; Width: 0; Channels: 1.

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include "npp.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2\core\core.hpp>
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

void display_image(Mat image);

int main() {

    //Read image and display attributes
    Mat Input_Image = imread("Test_Image.png");
    Mat Output_Image;
    display_image(Input_Image);
    int nHeight = Input_Image.rows;
    int nWidth = Input_Image.cols;
    int nChannels = Input_Image.channels();
    cout << "Height: " << nHeight << "; Width: " << nWidth << "; Channels: " << nChannels << endl;

    unsigned char* Dev_Image = NULL;
    cudaMalloc(&Dev_Image, nHeight*nWidth*2);
    cudaMemcpy(Dev_Image, Input_Image.data, nHeight*nWidth*nChannels, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    NppStatus errStatus;
    NppiSize Size;
    Size.width = nWidth;
    Size.height = nHeight;

    errStatus = nppiRGBToCbYCr422_8u_C3C2R(Input_Image.data, nWidth * sizeof(int) * 3, Dev_Image, nWidth * sizeof(int) * 2, Size);
    cudaMemcpy(Output_Image.data, Dev_Image, nHeight*nWidth*2, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    //Convert(Input_Image.data, nHeight, nWidth, nChannels);
    cout << "Height: " << Output_Image.rows << "; Width: " << Output_Image.cols << "; Channels: " << Output_Image.channels() << endl;
    display_image(Output_Image);
    system("pause");
    cudaFree(Dev_Image);
    return 0;

}

void display_image(Mat Image) {
    imshow("Image", Image);
    waitKey(0);
    destroyAllWindows();
}
```

Comment: Hope [this](https://github.com/felipunky/ProblemSet1) helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realised I was making two mistakes - 
1)Not setting up the output image correctly - (Mat Output_Image -> Mat Output_Image(Size(Width, Height), CV8UC2)

2) NPP conversion format takes in BGRA image. Converted input image from BGR to BGRA and conversion was successful.

Additionally changed the step arguments in the NPP conversion function to be Image.step